# How do I transfer an integer to __constant__ device memory?

Tags: memory, cuda

I have a weird problem, so I thought I would ask and see if someone more experienced than me could see a solution.

I am writing a program with CUDA C/C++, and I have some constant integers that specify various things, like coordinates of the bounds of the calculation, etc.. Currently I just have those things in global device memory. They are accessed by every thread in every kernel call, and so I figured that if they are in global memory, then they never are being cached or broadcast (right?). And so these little integers are taking up a lot (relatively) of overhead, and have a lot of 'read redundancy.'

So I declare in a header:

```
__constant__ int* number;
```

I include that header, and, when I do memory stuff, I do:

```
cutilSafeCall( cudaMemcpyToSymbol(number, &(some_host_int), sizeof(int) );
```

I pass `number` into all my kernel's then:

```
__global__ void magical_kernel(int* number, ...){

   //and I access 'number' like this
   int data_thingy = big_array[ *number ];

}
```

My code crashes. With number in global memory, it is just fine. I have determined that it crashes sometime upon accessing number within the kernel. This means that either I am accessing or allocating it wrong. If it holds the wrong value, it will also cause a crash, because it is used to index into arrays.

To conclude, I will ask a few questions. First, what am I doing wrong? As a bonus: is there a better way than constant memory to accomplish this task - I don't know the value of `number` at compile time, so a simple #define won't work. Will constant memory even speed the code up at all, or has it been cached and broadcasted all along? Could I somehow put the data in shared memory for each threadblock and have it remain in shared memory through multiple kernel calls?

Comment: Use int instead of int*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. You have declared `number` as a pointer, but never assigned it a value which is valid address in GPU memory
2. You have a variable scope onflict: the argument variable `int * number` defined in `magic_kernel` *is not the same variable* as the `__constant__ int * variable` defined as compilation unit scope.
3. The first argument of the `cudaMemcpyToSymbol` call is almost certainly incorrect.

If you don't understand why either of the first two point are true, you have some revision to do on pointers and scope in C++.

Based on your response to a now deleted answer, I suspect what you are actually trying to do is this:

```
__constant__ int number;

__global__ void magical_kernel(...){

   int data_thingy = big_array[ number ];

}

cudaMemcpyToSymbol("number", &(some_host_int), sizeof(int));
```

i.e. `number` is intended to be an integer in constant memory, not a pointer, and not a kernel argument.

---

EDIT: here is an exmaple which shows this in action:

```
#include <cstdio>

__constant__ int number;

__global__ void magical_kernel(int * out)
{
   out[threadIdx.x] = number;
}

int main()
{
    const int value = 314159;
    const size_t sz = size_t(32) * sizeof(int);
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol("number", &value, sizeof(int));

    int * _out, * out;

    out = (int *)malloc(sz);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&_out, sz);

    magical_kernel<<<1,32>>>(_out);

    cudaMemcpy(out, _out, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
        fprintf(stdout, "%d %d\n", i, out[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

You should be able to run this yourself and confirm it works as advertised.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I had put in number as an argument is because I had been caught up with the way you have to pass references to all data to kernels. I still find it weird that the string literal is the first argument to cudaMemcpyToSymbol; I don't doubt its correctness, just odd.

Comment: It isn't that odd - the API is going to fetch the virtual address of the variable from the context symbol table, that is why the argument is a character array - for the lookup. You can also pass the symbol by address too, *if* you know it.

Comment: I tried what you said, but the program still exits with a CUDA memory error at the memCpyToSymbol line. The only way I can get it not to error is to pass the variable name not in quotes, which is a plain int. Then, the number contains the value 0 when I try to access it, which obviously is also incorrect. Could it have something to do with the fact that number is defined, allocated, and used in three separate files (although the files in which it is allocated and used include the header file in which it is defined)?

Comment: CUDA doesn't support external linkage. I would guess you have a code structure/compilation problem. I have edited my answer to include a complete, compilable, runnable example which shows how it should work.